# Name for has_many :through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building simple site for saving links and have two models: `Board` and `Link`. `Board` has many `links` and `Link` belongs to `board`. So I have these board of links.

Board can be feed for other board. For example:

```
Board 1 :
- links 1

Board 2 : 
- links 2

Board 3 (feeds: Board 1, Board 2) so links are:
- links 3
- links 1
- links 2
```

I setup self referenced relationship. 
`Board` - `has_many :feeds, through: ...` and here is my problem, can't find good name for this through join model. It's some kind of link list like relationship. I thought about `FeedEntry` or something like this, but maybe you have better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change `feeds` table to `sources`, and then join table will be `feeds`.